# Normalizing Flow Penalization

Tags: statistics, optimization, machine-learning

I am looking to fit a normalizing flow, specifically a Masked Autoregressive Flow model. However, this model leads to high variance on lower dimensional, less complex data. I am using a neural network to parameterize the scale and shift components of the MAF. I think we need to smooth the loss surface, i.e., the log likelihood of the normalizing flow. Is there any literature outlining good ideas or what would be a good starting point? More generally, are there any papers that have a solid theoretical foundation to defining a penalty that can smooth something like a normalizing flow?

Comment: Why do you think that you should use special regularizers for normalizing flows? Why not try the L1 or L2 norm of the weights in the normalizing flow?

Comment: We want to try smoothing out the loss surface more explicitly. L1/L2 doesn't do that really/well enough. Something like a roughness penalty could maybe be good, but we can't find a good justification for it.